# Time complexity (Big O) for JavaScript Set

Tags: javascript, performance

We can find unique elements of array using JavaScript `Set()`. You can create a set by either giving array initially or use `Set.prototype.add()`. What are time complexities and space complexities for each case?

**With constructor**

```js
const mySet = new Set(nElementsArray);
```

**With add() method**

```js
const mySet = new Set();
for (const item of nElementsArray) {
  mySet.add(item);
}
```

For each of above what will be space and time complexity?

Comment: The implementation details for how Set methods are implemented are not part of the language specification. One would *hope* that set operations would be something close to constant-time, but nothing forces an implementation to do that.

Comment: Seems like you should write perf tests and figure out what is better for your use case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this has partial answer i guess, what i concerned is, whether providing entire array to the constructor is efficient than adding one by one. This question you mentioned is more about accessing existing elements and it compares with  other forms of data structures

Comment: `add` has `O(1)` average complexity. Both approaches you've shown are iterating over `nElementsArray`, which has linear time complexity (on the number of elemenets in the array), so it can't get better than `O(n)`. While the complexity of the `Set` constructor is not specified, it is very unlikely that it is worse.